# Error while fetching Hardware Info in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, hardware-id

I have a C# project where I am trying to deploy a protection mechanism by registering a combination of the Hardware IDs.

I am using the `ManagementObjectSearcher` Class for the same. Here are some of the commands:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher cpuget = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_processor");
ManagementObjectSearcher mainboardget = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_BaseBoard");
ManagementObjectSearcher biosget = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_BIOS");
```

For fetching the IDs I have:

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in cpuList)
    {
        cpuid = mo["ProcessorID"].ToString();
    }
foreach (ManagementObject mo in mainboardlist)
    {
        mbid = mo["SerialNumber"].ToString();
    }
```

This has been working fine. However, ****in some machines(I tested on 10 PCs and two were defaulters)**** the error message showed up.

`Reference not set to Instance of an Object`

Why so? Please Help.

Comment: These 2 pc what os they have?

Comment: Some of them return null for `mo["XXXX"]`. Check for null before `.ToString()`

Comment: @kostasch. All PCs have Win7 x86

Comment: @L.B Even I thought so :). So I made some dummy builds which where I checked the output for each Hardware string. Same error.

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Comment: @EdwindeKoning the second `foreach` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most difficult problems have the silliest of Answers. Period.

All I had to do was Check for a null component in the management object class.

```
foreach (ManagementObject mo in cpuget.Get())
 {
    if (mo["ProcessorID"] != null)
    cpuid = mo.GetPropertyValue("ProcessorID").ToString();
 }
```

The similar would be for `mbid`.

What a dufus? :|

**P.S.**: @[L.B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/932418/l-b) suggested this. More power to him.